# How to specify "max_analyzed_offset" when querying elasticsearch using org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am using
spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 3.0.5
with elasticsearch 8.7.0

```
@Repository
public interface EsRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SearchResult, String> {

    @Query("{\"query_string\": {\"query\": \"?0\"} }")
    @Highlight(
            fields = {
                    @HighlightField(name = "attachment.content")
            },
            parameters = @HighlightParameters(
                    preTags = "<strong>",
                    postTags = "/<strong>",
                    fragmentSize = 300,
                    numberOfFragments = 1
            )
    )
    List<SearchHit<SearchResult>> queryAllFieldsByQueryStringHighlighting(String queryTerm, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When loading a large document that exceeds 1000000 characters I am encountering:

```
doc[0]/index[test_index] exceeds the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] limit [1000000]. To avoid this error, set the query parameter [max_analyzed_offset] to a value less than index setting [1000000] and this will tolerate long field values by truncating them."
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html
documents that there are several query parameters that can be set when executing a highlighting query, which includes "max_analyzed_offset"

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.HighlightParameters provides a way to specify many of the options documented on the page specified above, however I don't see an attribute for "max_analyzed_offset".  Is there a way to specify "max_analyzed_offset" when using org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository to query elasticsearch?

As a side know I am aware that the index can be configured to increase "highlight.max_analyzed_offset" to a value higher than 1000000 characters, however I would prefer to specify max_analyzed_offset as a query option.

I reviewed org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.HighlightParameters interface and did not see an attribute that seemed to set max_analyzed_offset